# C++ String.substr Outputs Incorrectly

Tags: c++, string, substring

Trying to split a string out into parts. The format will always be like this `name from number on date`

need to split out `name`, `number`, and `date`

code:

```
string name, number, date;

size_t from = s.find(" from ");
size_t on = s.find(" on ");

name = s.substr(0, from);
number = s.substr(from + 6, on);
date = s.substr(on + 4);

cout << "name:" << name << ", num:" << number << ", date:" << date << endl;
```

sample input: `John Smith from N656 on 01012013`

sampe output: `name:John Smith, num: N656 on 01012013, date:01012013`

So there's obviously a problem when trying to create the substring `number` but I'm very curious what could be causing this since the other two are working.

Comment: [Look closer.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Comment: I don't think number should print out `"N656 on 01012013"` even if it worked as you expected it to, rather it'd print out `"N656"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're assuming that `s.substr` accepts start/end index.

This is what it actually is:
`s.substr(pos, size)`

> **pos** position of the first character to include
>   **size** length of substring

So, in an ugly way:

```
name = s.substr(0, from);
number = s.substr(from + 6, on - (from + 6));
date = s.substr(on + 4);
```

Comment: It can be ugly. I've been staring at C++ all day and I think I'm actually getting worse. Thanks!

Comment: @frankV: Keep in mind that you can also initialize a string with a pair of iterators to get a substring: `string name(&s[0], &s[from]); string number(&s[from + 6], &s[on]); string date( &s[on + 4], &s[s.size()]);` However, still not pretty...  I don't know which one I prefer less.